# Cannot add SKSpriteNode dynamically?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm adding `SKSpriteNode` dynamically on `didBeginContact` delegate method :

Here is my code

```
 -(void)adBall
    {
        SKSpriteNode *obj = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"ball.png"];
        obj.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:obj.texture size:obj.texture.size];
        obj.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
        obj.name = OBSTACLE_KEY;

        obj.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = BallCategory1;
        obj.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = GreenLineCategory | RedLineCategory ;;
        obj.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = GreenLineCategory | RedLineCategory ;;

        obj.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
        obj.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        obj.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
        obj.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0f;
        obj.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f;
        obj.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
        [obj.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(200, 300)];
    }

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }

    if ([firstBody.node.name isEqual: OBSTACLE_KEY] && ( [secondBody.node.name isEqual: BLACKLINE_KEY]))
    {
        [self adBall];
    }
}
```

But cant appear in screen it just show ball at bottom and disappear.

and if add `[self adBall];` in `didMoveToView` method than working fine.

So Plz tell me where I'm wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

You never run

```
[self addChild:obj];
```

inside your adBall method. Therefore the newly created sprite won't be added to the scene graph and naturally won't be drawn (it gets discarded at the end of the method).

Comment: thx. i add line there but it works when i call method in didMoveToView delegate method. Not working in didBeginContact.

Answer (score 0):

Ok  Done it.

as `LearnCocos2D` said that i didn't add `[self addChild:obj];` i add that line but than it not working in `didMoveToView` than what i did is called method after some time.

Like :

```
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self adBall];
    });
```

Comment: makes no sense and shouldn't be necessary, you probably have another bug and now apply an "addChild workaround" that just happens to fix what you assume to be the problem, but the real issue is definitely something else.